# How to assign roles to subtypes?

Tags: database, oop, authorization

I need to store objects with 3 roles: **Employee**, **Manager**, **Admin**. The common attributes of these objects I will store as **User**. So should I store the role attribute for the **User**?

- If I store it, then the table name would be **Employee**, and all data in it would have the role as **Employee**, it seems redundant. Or data could conflict, it is a subtype of **Employee** but with the **Admin** role, for example.
- If I don't store it, then during authorization, I have to check the typeof of the object?